# RN rendering the view but show white blank screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this code and when I run the program all I get is white screen. there is no errors and I can see my log so I know the program rendered and running. My guess is , that it's some issue with the `<View/>` style, but I cant fine the issue.

So the logic here is that I basically run a function inside the rendered view that check if there is a token in memory, and based on this information render one of two cases.

CODE:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center'
  })

  checkToken = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
    .then((res) => {
      res = JSON.parse(res)
      console.log('this is checkToken()',res.token)
      this.renderUserSection(res.token)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
    .done();
  }


  renderUserSection =  (token) => {
    if(token === undefined) { 
        console.log('render UserSection')
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.Signup.bind(this)} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>SignUp</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>

      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.Login.bind(this)} style={styles.buttonLogin}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>
     )
    } else {
      if (!this.state.loading) {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.state.path ? this.renderMap() : this.renderCamera()}       
          </View>
        );
      } return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Loader loading={this.state.loading}/> 
        </View>
      ) 
    }
}


  render() {
   return (
    <View>{this.checkToken()}</View>
   ) 
  }
```

before that code I run en example that was:

```
  render() {
   return this.renderUserSection()
  }
```

and everything worked fine. Now I write it inside some logic and It's render the program (based on log) but the view is blank.

Answer (score 1):

from [`React#height-and-width`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html)

> A component can only expand to fill available space if its parent has dimensions greater than 0. If a parent does not have either a fixed width and height or flex, the parent will have dimensions of 0 and the flex children will not be visible.

There is no `height` and `width` provided to `View`.

So,even screen rendered, it is coming blank as.

assign `height` and `width` to container style object.

```
container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height : 200,
    width : 200
  })
```

Also,check with `flex` property.

Comment: yup it worked. That kind a was my guess but I wasn't sure what exactly went wrong because before the logic it actually worked so why is this suddenly needs height and width you know? lol any way if someone else is have this problem I actually added `height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width` so it fit any screen.

Comment: @obiwankenoobi please accept n upvite it if its working for you. Glad to help you

Comment: hey! sorry for miss leading but its not working, I accidentally run the test example `render() {
   return this.renderUserSection()
  } ` which was always working

Comment: Could you please set the background color for cotainer.Please check it showing or not?

Comment: it show only when I add it like that `<View style={styles.container}>{this.checkToken()}</View>` which is strange because I also have container style at the other `<View/>` inside  `renderUserSection `

Comment: I still not sure how Is that fixing the issue? I did added `height` and `width` to  `container` and added `styles.container` to `<View style={styles.container}>{this.checkToken()}</View>`. what should I change?

Comment: @obiwankenoobi could please share rhe repo if its fine for u

Comment: I can't share the repo but here is a snippets of App.js which is basically the full app. hope you can find something there https://pastebin.com/KFqYKt3A